# I want to Display news and events in a html page such that automatically they are rotating but on mouseover they stop?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to Display news and events in a html page such that automatically they are rotating but on mouseover they stop? Please give me any article link related this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for such type you can first try searching in search engines [eg. google] and you can post the errors that you encounter while implementing..

check out the link:

http://www.webstylepress.com/jquery-smooth-news-rotator/